# ASP Net MVC Using global variables to pass data between controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I'm learn C# and I'm trying do something here, I have a aspnet mvc application, that contains authentication, I want get the user information when he make login, and save inside a global variable, for access any controller or any service, so I create a BaseController, that inherits from Controller class and each of mine controller inherits from BaseController, when I login I save inside basecontroller, but when I get data from basecontroller inside my controller it's return null.

Can someone give me a example how to do that, or tell if this a good practice?

Comment: MVC is stateless. You can't save a variable from one session to another without using things like cookies, session or tempdata. There are built in, native ways to address what you want that are safer and more secure than trying to build your own. I'd recommend researching the already existing myriad of ways to do that.

Comment: As commented above, [Security, Authentication, and Authorization with ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/) is a good resource for guidance.

Comment: So, Thanks i will reasearch more about it

Comment: User login information is already avaiable in any controller (after authentication). Just call `User` inside of your action and you'll get what you need.

Comment: But, i have created a blank project with "No Authentication"

Answer (score -2):

As long as the user is still authenticated then you can use variables called Session variables. Below is an example of storing a string that can be accessed between controllers.

```
Session["AccessLevel"] = "ADMIN";
```

Once the user is logged off or times out, the variable will be removed by the garbage collection. I experimented with having a few Gigabytes of information stored in a Session variable.

Comment: The session state is stored in a cookie so it is possible to have it hijacked, however if you are using SSL on the site then you will be fine

Comment: Nope - _"user logged off"_ and _"(session) times out"_ are different concepts. Your code above has nothing to do with log in/out.